# Google Chrome, float, and media queries

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-float, media-queries

I'm having a problem where Google Chrome sometimes incorrectly renders a floated element. More specifically, the markup looks like this:

```
<h1>
    Headline
    <small>Sub-heading</small>
</h1>
```

This is styled using this simple CSS:

```
h1 small {
    display: block;
}

@media (min-width: 750px) {
    h1 small {
        float: right;
    }
}
```

(here is a link to a jsfiddle.com which demonstrates the problem in action: http://jsfiddle.net/ys6L88r8/1/)

As you can see, the element is floated within a media query. When loading the page, if the browser window width exceeds the width specified in the media query, everything looks fine. However, if you resize the browser below this point and then back up again, the element incorrectly appears below the h1.

Is this a Google Chrome bug? I have verified that it works correctly in Firefox and Safari 8. I'm using Google Chrome 40.0.2214.91 (64-bit) for OS X.

Comment: Unable to replicate in Chrome 41.0.2272.17 beta-m (64-bit) on W7

Comment: you were trying to say below but at right?

Comment: I meant that you resize the browser window so that it's smaller than the width specified in the media query. If you then make the window bigger again (so that it exceeds the media query break point), the floated element will be incorrectly positioned below the h1. It will be floated to the right, yes, but it's too far down on the page. Compare this position with the position you get if you reload the page in a browser window wider than the media query break point.

Comment: mhmmm I confirm strange behaviour in Chrome 40.....

Comment: i'm using vsn 38 - no issue (on windows)

Comment: Verified that this is a Google Chrome bug: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=411256

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is a verified bug in Google Chrome: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=411256