# Media Query wont work in simple website on chrome but does in firefox

Tags: html, css, width, device, viewport

Hi guys i made a simple webpage with a couple of divs and a background image. Basically i wanted the background image to disappear if the width of the device is smaller.

But when i minimize to width of browser to less than 500px the media query only works for firefox and not for chrome.

Additionaly here http://pastebin.com/TZ1UwVmK is a link to the code. You can substitute the background image for https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/broadway/bg.png .

```
enter code here

    <code><pre>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

        <head>
            <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400, 600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
            <link href='testnew1.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />  <!-- used to give phones a background in place of image that doesn't show up for unknown reason -->
    <style>
    .container-in-headerdiv { max-width: 940px;
.container-in-headerdiv { max-width: 940px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0 10px;}


.header {background-color: #333333;}
.nav{list-style-type:none;
        margin:0;
        padding: 20px 0;}

.jumbotron { background: url('images/projectbroadway-pic.png') no-repeat center center;
        background-color: #333333;  /* gives lavender color if image doesn't load */
        background-size: cover;
        height:800px;} /* not centered, or positioned except its properties as a div under normal flow */
@media (max-width: 500px) {  /* relies on viewport to give width, gives lavender color if image doesnt load */
        .jumbotron{
        background-image:none;
          background: #E6E6FA;
          background-size: cover;
          height:800px;} 
          }
}
.container-in-jumbotron{max-width: 940px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0 10px;}
.main { position: relative; /* this class not working at all atm */
        top: 180px;
        text-align: center;}
.btn-main{ background-color: #333333;
color:#ffffff;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
font-weight: 600;
font-size: 18px;
letter-spacing: 1.3px;
padding: 16px 40px;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

    </style>


        </head>

        <body>

            <div class="header">
                <div class="container-in-headerdiv">

                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li>About</li>
                        <li>Work</li>
                        <li>Team</li>
                        <li>Contact</li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div>

        <div class="jumbotron">
          <div class="container-in-jumbotron">  
            <div class="main">
              <h1>We are Broadway</h1>
              <a class="btn-main" href="#">Get started</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        </body>
    </html>
    </pre></code>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have use background when updating the background of jumbotron not background-color:

```
.jumbotron{
            background: #E6E6FA;
            background-size: cover;
            height:800px;
        }
```

Comment: thanks , I updated the code, please check it out. It works in explorer firefox and on smartphone but not on chrome

Comment: Should be this: 'code' .jumbotron {
        background: #E6E6FA;
        background-size: cover;
        height:800px;
    }

Answer (score 0):

This is because you use 'background-color' in your media query instead of 'background'

Try

```
<code><pre>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400, 600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <link href='testnew1.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />      <!-- used to give phones a background in place of image that doesn't show up for unknown reason -->
<style>
.container-in-headerdiv { max-width: 940px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 10px;}


.header {
    background-color: #333333;
}

.nav{ 
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding: 20px 0;}

.jumbotron { background: url('https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-        content/projects/broadway/bg.png') no-repeat center center;
    background-color: #333333;  /* gives lavender color if image doesn't load */
    background-size: cover;
    height:800px;} /* not centered, or positioned except its properties as a     div under normal flow */
@media (max-width: 500px) {  /* relies on viewport to give width, gives lavender color if image doesnt load */
    .jumbotron {
        background: none;
        background-color: #E6E6FA;
        background-size: cover;
        height:800px;
    }
}
.container-in-jumbotron { 
    max-width: 940px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.main {
    position: relative; /* this class not working at all atm */
    top: 180px;
    text-align: center;
}

.btn-main {
    background-color: #333333;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 1.3px;
    padding: 16px 40px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}     
</style>


</head>

<body>

    <div class="header">
        <div class="container-in-headerdiv">

            <ul class="nav">
                <li>About</li>
                <li>Work</li>
                <li>Team</li>
                <li>Contact</li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>

<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container-in-jumbotron">  
    <div class="main">
      <h1>We are Broadway</h1>
      <a class="btn-main" href="#">Get started</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
</pre></code>
```

works in chrome for me

Comment: I updated the code please check it out, it works in firefox and explorer and on smartphone. just not on chrome.

Comment: Hey your code works but not when I put the css on to a different file. Could you take a look at my screenshot and tell me whats wrong please?

http://imgur.com/2YhKUy9

Comment: Sorry, I can't see anything on this screenshot :-/

Comment: http://pastebin.com/YgJv5MMA
http://i.imgur.com/buTLjzp.png image enlarges in new tab, sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

update Here is the pastebin pastebin.com/YgJv5MMA Here is the screenshot i.imgur.com/buTLjzp.png

It now works on safari, opera, smartphone, edge, and explorer. I have Google Chrome 47.0.2526.80 (Official Build) m (32-bit).

I have also found answers that say there is a bug with resizing windows in chrome browser and media queries here [Google Chrome, float, and media queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28174782/google-chrome-float-and-media-queries) and here  [Weird float rendering in Chrome when using media queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16024837/weird-float-rendering-in-chrome-when-using-media-queries?rq=1)

Oh well , I'm moving on.

EDIT 
FOUND PROBLEM.  Was linking the html and css files through dropbox. I took the two files and put them on my local desktop and now the media query works when the page is minimized to less than 500px width. So i guess i wont be using dropbox. Thanks for looking into this for me.

HERE was the html and css pastebin.com/YgJv5MMA